# Filter and Group in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0, xslt-grouping

I am trying to filter data and then group using XSLT. Here is my XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AccumulatedOutput>
    <root>
        <Header>
            <Add>true</Add>
            <Name>Subscriber</Name>
            <Value>SAC</Value>
        </Header>
    </root>
    <root>
        <Header>
            <Add>true</Add>
            <Name>System</Name>
            <Value>CBP</Value>
        </Header>
    </root>
    <root>
        <Header>
            <Add>false</Add>
            <Name>Subscriber</Name>
            <Value>SAC</Value>
        </Header>
    </root>
</AccumulatedOutput>
```

What I want to do is that group based on `Header/Name` and but remove the group in which `Header/Add` is false. 
So in above example I there will be two groups created (one for `Name=Subscriber` and other for `Name=System`) but since the first group(with `Name=Subscriber`) contains `Add=false` , I want to ignore that and my output should only have one node in it , like below

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <Header>
        <Name>System</Name>
        <Value>CBP</Value>
        <Add>true</Add>
    </Header>
</root>
```

I tried using group by method but I can't figure out a way to filter it.
It will be a great help if someone can give me some pointers

Thanks

Comment: Please select either XSLT 1.0 or 2.0, not both.

Comment: I don't mind using either of them to solve this problem  hence used both

Comment: What do you want to do with groups that contain more than one item, do you want to merge them somehow or only output all the items?

Comment: Only output all the items but if skip that group which has Add=false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0, you could do:

```
<xsl:template match="/AccumulatedOutput">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="root/Header" group-by="Name">
            <xsl:if test="not(current-group()/Add='false')">
                <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </root>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

**No explicit XSLT conditional instructions**:

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each-group group-by="Name" select=
        "root/Header[for $n in string(Name)
                      return every $h in /*/root/Header[Name eq $n] 
                                     satisfies not($h/Add eq 'false')]">
              <xsl:sequence select="current-group()"/>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </root>
</xsl:template>
```